# Max-Min Strategy equal pay-offs

Tags: game-theory

[image: Pay-Off Matrix]

I have this pay-off matrix above which i try to find its max-min strategies but when i apply the max-min rule pay-offs are equal so i kinda get confused since i am a newbie to game theory. I would be appreciated if you can help me about this.

Answer (score 0):

you have:\begin{array}{c|c}1\setminus2&L&R\\\hline L&2,-2&-2, 2\\\hline R&-2, 2&2,-2\end{array}
first let's change it to:\begin{array}{c|c}1\setminus2&L&R\\\hline L&2&-2\\\hline R&-2&2\end{array}
where the number is the cost from player $(2)$ to player $(1)$

Now let's say that for player $(1)$ there is $(p)$ chance to chose $L$ therefore $(1-p)$ for $R$.

so if $(2)$ plays $L$ $(1)$ gain is: $2p-2(1-p)$

and if $(2)$ plays $R$ $(1)$ gain is: $-2p+2(1-p)$

therefore:$$-2p+2(1-p)=2p-2(1-p)\implies 0=0$$this is probably not what you thought you will get but this actually is the answer, it implies that there is no dominant strategy. i recommend to read a bit here: [link](http://physics.ujep.cz/~jskvor/KVM/TeorieHer/shoham.pdf)

it explain a bit about the meaning behind minimax strategy and have a real nice visualize

Comment: So, basically you are saying that there is no max-min strategy for row or column player ?

Comment: @Tartar yes, there is no strategy in that will  min-max this game

Comment: but how come you get this result only by calculating for player 1 ? I dont really get the logic.

Comment: I am looking for maxmin strategies, I dont know if that is different than minimax though.

Comment: @Tartar max min = min max in sum 0 games. I can't remember the proof that doesn't use matrix space so you can search it if you want the proof, and the strategy of that max min/min max called minimax

Comment: @Tartar read in the link. Sorry I can't give a straight answer, last time I worked with game-theory was more than a year ago so I only remember the equations and not the proofs/logic